# Find the general solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Q. Find the general solution of the non-homogeneous equation.

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}+y=te^t$$

So here are my steps:

1. Find $\mu (t)=e^t$
2. $y(t) e^t= \int e^t \times te^t$

   So, I combined the terms and obtained:
3. $y(t) e^t= \int te^{2t} $

and from there I proceeded by integration by parts and got:

$$y(t) e^t= \frac{1}{2}t e^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}+c $$

then I divided by $e^t$
$$y(t)= \frac{\frac{1}{2}t e^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}+c}{e^t} $$

After simplifying, I obtained:
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^t[t-\frac{1}{2}]+c$$

which is the general solution.

I just want to someone to verify if I did everything correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost: The correct solution is actually $$y(t)=\frac 12e^t\left(t-\frac 12\right)+ce^{-t}$$

Consider substituting this solution into your differential equation to verify that this is, indeed, a solution.

When I substituted your "solution" $y(t)=\frac 12 e^t(t-\frac 12)+c$, I ended up getting $$\frac{dy}{dt}+y=te^t+c.$$ The RHS of the above is not equal to $te^t$.

Comment: I must have made a mistake in my simplification. I shall put my simplification on my post.

Comment: Oh! I see it now.

Comment: I forgot to divide c by $e^t$

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't even know you can substitute.